# Why can't I source a script file from .xsessionrc?

Tags: scripting, login, lxde

I am running LXDE/Openbox on Debian Linux. On logging in I want to:

- add a user specific directory to the $PATH variable (A)
- execute some (non-graphical) commands (e.g. mount directories) (B)

The setup should work for graphical login as well as login shells (e.g. SSH). Especially the part about extending the $PATH variable seems to be tricky...

My ideal solution would be to put all the commands (A and B) in a separate script file (F) and source it from `.xsessionrc` (for graphical login via the session manager) and `.profile` (for login shells).
Sourcing F from `.profile` works nicely, but sourcing from `.xsessionrc` seems to fail.

So I made the workaround to set the new $PATH directly in `.xsessionrc` (and also in `.profile`) and just execute F (now containing only the commands B) from `.xsessionrc` and `.profile`. This works fine, but is not really satisfactory, as I now some duplicate commands (A) in `.xessionrc` and `.profile`.

Is there some magic incanation that I have to do in order to source another file from `.xsessionrc` or are there any other obvious flaws in my thinking?

Comment: `The setup should work for graphical login as well as login shells (e.g. ssh)` login shells won't do anything with xsessionrc, seeing as you aren't starting X.

Comment: Right, that's why I also want to source the file from .profile for the login shells.

Comment: if it's all stuff like mounting, you can do it from .bash_profile or similar. It'll still get run before the xsession starts. No need to have it in multiple places.

Comment: I just did a test and put some commands into .bash_profile (yes, my shell is bash): they didn't get executed when logging in graphically.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder what user your xsession is starting from then. I forgot not everybody logs in then does startx / xinit.

Comment: No idea, how can I find out?

Comment: When you say "sourcing from .xsessionrc seems to fail.", please describe exactly what you are doing and the nature of the failure.

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason why sourcing a file, with the standard *sourcing* command, that is `.` not `source` (which is a cshism also supported by tcsh, bash, ksh and zsh but not standard) wouldn't work from `.xsessionrc`.

You have to make sure the syntax in the sourced file is standard `sh` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this in `.xsessionrc` and not e.g. in `.bash_profile` or whatever other file your shell uses on *login* (don't confuse with `.bashrc`, which is sourced by each shell)? Here (Fedora) it even has a helpful comment `User specific environment and startup programs`...

Comment: The commands should also be executed when no bash (or any other shell) gets executed. E.g. the remote directories should also be mounted when only starting a file manager

Comment: @BinaryBongo Many setups do read `.profile` when logging in with a display manager. It does depend on the distribution, display manager and session type, I haven't verified whether your does read `.profile`. If it doesn't, put `. ~/.profile` in your `.xsessionrc`.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your distro, you can add scripts to run automatically on boot. If you're using initscripts, they'd be added to rc.local (/etc/rc.local IIRC) and with systemd I believe you'd make a service file for them and then enable it so it ran on boot.

[With debian, it'd be initscripts and thus `rc.local`.](https://superuser.com/questions/451296/how-to-add-a-command-in-etc-rc-local-file)

Mounting should be done with `/etc/fstab` which will run on boot.

Comment: This is not applicable here. The requirement is to run some code at session startup time, not at system boot time.